# line numbers in vim -H reversed

Tags: line-numbers

Recently I installed vim 8.2 on Windows 10 and vim 8.1.2269 on Linux Ubuntu.

Both are compiled with `+rightleft` option. When I use `gvim -H` or `vim -H` (without vimrc file) and run `:set number`, I get line numbers on the right side (as it should be).

However, the line numbers between 10 and 99 appear *reversed*, i.e., 01,11,21,32,..., unlike in the previous versions of vim.

Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! `-H` is called "Hebrew mode" in the docs, and it sets `hkmap` and `rightleft`; could this perhaps be *expected*?

Comment: @d-ben-knoble: If you meant "it's not a bug, it's a feature", then definitely - not!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it turns out, this was an obscure bug, that was caused by patch [8.1.1073](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/e73f911c53de1c87e39456ba20782f72a0ca8f4f).

I have just submitted a [patch](https://github.com/vim/vim/pull/8391) to fix this [issue](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/8389) and it has just been included as of [Patch v8.2.3012](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/29f0dc3689eafcf7888e06d57d1cf79e62c5c148)